# How is D'Qar supposed to be pronounced?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, pronunciation

In *The Force Awakens*, the Resistance's base is located on a planet called **D'Qar**.

Like *Kashyyyk*, this is another instance of writers choosing weird spellings for names in a SciFi universe.

However, unlike *Kashyyyk*, I have a hard time seeing how one is supposed to pronounce *D'Qar*. I would instinctively pronounce it `/dːkɑɹ/` but I wouldn't bet my life on it, especially for the pronunciation of *Q*.

Is there any canon source (interviews of people working on the movie for example) which explains how *D'Qar* is supposed to be pronounced?

Comment: I'd pronounce it like DER CAR.

Comment: I'm not sure what counts as canon. Even something as stupidly simple as _Jakku_ is pronounced differently by different characters in the film.

Comment: No audio books available so far i think (and knowing how many of them mangle pronounciation, I'd not trust one). No interviews mentioned that name yet that I'm aware of. No DVD commentary available yet for obvious reasons. I suspect you'll be lucky if we find out the correct answer till 6 months from now or so.

Comment: @DVK The DVD should be out in April, which is 4 months. I hoped that this planet got mentioned in an interview, but apparently not...

Comment: I've been pronouncing it "duh car", emphasis on car. PS - canon has one n in it.

Comment: @TylerH Another case of hypercorrection, it has one in my language for both cannon and canon, and I wrongly assumed that canon was the one that took two n's in English... Thanks.

Comment: @MrLister Just like Han is pronounced "Hahn" or like "hand" depending on who's saying it.

Comment: @Fatalize - Pfft. Waiting for things is boring.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45116/which-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-han-in-star-wars

Comment: I think you’ve done something wrong with your IPA. /dːkɑɹ/ would be a word beginning with a long d, which is exceedingly rare cross-linguistically, and utterly impossible in English. Especially if followed directly by a k. Did you mean something like /dəˈkɑɹ/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The planet is mentioned in the [audiobook version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011PVVH22) of the Star Wars novel "[***Lost Stars***](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Stars)" by Claudia Gray

As narrated by Pierce Craven, the pronunciation is 'du-**K**aar' although he does have a slight tendency to slur the last syllable, rendering it more like "du-Kaar-**ah**" on at least one occasion.

[Listen to a clip here](http://picosong.com/QWBT)

Comment: U D'Man.  (Too bad there's a 15 chars minimum).

Comment: @SredniVashtar - You could always say it twice.